# Error when trying to load taxonomy term name from tid

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I am trying to replace a view name with the name of a taxonomy term that is determined from a url argument.

When I explicitly set `$tid`, the following works flawlessly:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $tid = 2;
  $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
  $name = $term->label();
  $view->setTitle($name);
}
```

However, if `$tid` is determined from my argument, as in:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $tid = $view->args[0];
  // or alternatively $tid = intval($view->args[0]);
  $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
  $name = $term->label();
  $view->setTitle($name);
}
```

...then I get the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function label() on null in hook_views_pre_render()
```

...on the line containing `$name = $term->label()`.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening. When I inspect `kint($term)` in either situation, all of the data for the loaded term appears to be available. I've also verified that:

```
if   $tid1 = 2;
and  $tid2 = intval($view->args[0]);
then $tid1 === $tid2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is the case when no argument is passed and $tid is null. So better keep a check you have data in variable $tid and further perform the task. Even the view name condition is not mentioned so it may apply to all views.

```
  function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
      $tid = $view->args[0];
      // or alternatively $tid = intval($view->args[0]);
    if(isset($tid) && !empty($tid)){
      $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
      $name = $term->label();
      $view->setTitle($name);
    }
    }
```

Comment: So php will throw an error because there is the potential for it to be null? That seems so bizarre to me. I realize it's good practice for it to be within a conditional, but it was really throwing me off because I know that in this instance it is definitely not null.